# How do I count the total number of items in an array based on id and quantity?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `cart[]` array like this:

```
[
{item_id: "0001", qty: "1"},
{item_id: "0002", qty: "2"},
{item_id: "0005", qty: "3"},
{item_id: "0001", qty: "5"}
]
```

I am trying to count all the `qty` where `item_id == 0001` for example. The problem is, the `item_id` may be multiple times in the array; in this case twice. So I'm trying to add all the `qty` up into a single value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var this_item_qty = 0;

  $.each(cart, function(index, value) {
  if (value.item_id == "0001"){
     this_item_qty = this_item_qty + value.qty;
  }

  console.log(this_item_qty);
  // Returns 01 or 015...

});
```

But that doesn't seem to work. It's giving me values like `01` and `015`. It appears to be putting the values after another instead of calculating them together. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is taking the `value.qty` as a string and concatenating it. You need:

```
this_item_qty = this_item_qty + parseInt(value.qty);
```

This will convert the string to an integer. If you want to be really robust you could check the parsed value for `NaN` before adding it.

Comment: Thank you for the "fix" and the explanation. It's working! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Number(value.qty)`

```
var this_item_qty = 0;

  $.each(cart, function(index, value) {
  if (value.item_id == "0001"){
     this_item_qty = this_item_qty + Number(value.qty);
  }

  console.log(this_item_qty);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this_item_qty+= parseInt(value.qty)`